# Android phones server client over internet communication IP

Tags: android, streaming, client-server, ip-address, two-way

Im starting to work on Android app in which I will use two phones to communicate with each other. I planned to have that communication over internet, maybe if one phone publishes certain data on IP address, server,  and other opens that page(client). Problem is that I haven't god fixed IP address on any phone, can I pass that problem in any other way or I need to consider different ways for communication?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot directly connect two phones via internet, but you can use a middleware for this purpose. Main idea is that the first device send the message to this middleware (server) and the second periodically try to pull them.

There are many ready-to-use solutions for this purpose and the choice of solution depends on your case: which data type you want to transmit (text, binary, multemedia), how fast, etc. For instance for text messaging you can try to use [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)-protocol or may be [C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) framework will be enough.

Any way the most appropriate solution is to use one of the existed protocols or technologies.

Comment: Thank you, just for info, I'm working with video, want to send it from one phone to another over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If your phones are close together, you can try an ah hoc WiFi network. It seems like directly addressing one phone from another using the cellular Internet is about never possible. It could be possible sometimes for some providers if the two phones are in the same cell perhaps, but you can not rely on it.